# Graphic Error When Install Ubuntu 12.04 Guest on VMWare Player

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, vmware, vmware-player

I'm using windows Vista 32 bit, and I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 by using vmware player.
But after I install it, the Ubuntu desktop looks like this :

[image: Graphic Error]

Can someone help me please, is this a compatibility issue?
Thank you.

EDIT :

I tried using VirtualBox, but the I can not enter the desktop at all, I got stuck in tty, and if I pressed F7, this screen came out :

[image: Virtual Box Error]

Comment: It looks like the simulated hardware that VMware player generates for the VM doesn't play well with Ubuntu's GUI. Try playing with the settings of the VM (maybe enable Settings->Hardware->Display-Accelerate) or some of the options in Settings->Options->Unity. If nothing works, try also Virtualbox, it is also free of cost (and additionally open source) and might work better for you.

Comment: @MariosZindilis Hello, I tried virtualbox, and I described another error in my comment for Alex reply.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably Unity or some other dependency of it.  Unity is the graphical user interface for Ubuntu, and it's clearly pointing to the wrong...  Everything.

You should still be able to jump to another tty screen (another terminal interface) by using

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>

You can use any of <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>, they all have separate terminal states respectively.  Remember this utility when the GUI fails.

From the terminal, login with your username and password, then type

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Breakdown of commands with quick references.  If you don't know what the code is you're entering, you should always find out first, as a principal.  This promotes learning, and system stability.

"sudo" - admin command, if you run this before anything it will grant you root privileges when running the command (requires root password)

"apt-get" - this is a package manager application, use it to manage software and git repositories.  Very multifunctional.

"apt-get update" - updates the repositories and gets a list of any and all new software to be downloaded.

"apt-get install --reinstall" - full command broken down, apt-get (application), install (command to application, tells it to install a package), and --reinstall (optional command tagged to the install command.  Reinstalls the specified package)

"ubuntu-desktop" - contains many different software packages related to the Ubuntu desktop, and GUI.

EDIT

I see that comment now.  I never had a problem with virtual box, you should try it if this doesn't work.

Comment: I tried you suggestions on VMWare Player, it didn't work,
Then I tried to use VirtualBox, but I can not enter the desktop at all, stuck in the tty screen.
And when I tried to press ctrl+alt+F7, this screen came :
[link] (http://i1160.photobucket.com/albums/q498/dulipat/error_zpsa90ab910.jpg)

Any other suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: I'm at work right now, and a bit hung over, but I'll get back to you tonight after midnight sometime (-8pst)

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem, using Ubuntu 12.04 with VMPlayer 6.0 on a Windows 7 host. Unity doesn't seem to display correctly at all.

I have installed Xfce and it's ok then. Didn't try with Gnome 3.x, but I think it should work. So :

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4 xfce4-goodies
```

And then, disconnect and chose Xfce.